# Attacks that ByPass Multifactor Authentication (Necrobrowser in Office 365)

Tags: man-in-the-middle, multi-factor

I added MFA to Office 365, but a security specialist says it can be defeated with NecroBrowser, which can capture and transmit an already MFA-authenticated cookie.  I can't find any specifics about this.

What steps would a user need to take to install NecroBrowser?

Has this been patched?  Any links to the prevention and mitigation details?

Here is what I have done:

Read FBI warning in this post:
[FBI warns about attacks that bypass multi-factor authentication](https://www.zdnet.com/article/fbi-warns-about-attacks-that-bypass-multi-factor-authentication-mfa/)

Which discusses SIM swapping, which I understand.  But then it says with reference to a "Hack The Box" conference in June 2019:

> The Muraena tool intercepts traffic between a user and a target website where they are requested to enter login credentials and a token code as usual. Once authenticated, NecroBrowser stores the data for the victims of this attack and hijacks the session cookie, allowing cyber actors to log into these private accounts, take them over, and change user passwords and recovery e-mail addresses while maintaining access as long as possible.

I want to learn more about this, what users have to do to get exploited, whether it has been patched and how to prevent it beyond user education.  I've searched extensively but find very little else written about this exploit.  Can anyone help me understand it better or point me to detailed info?

Comment: I have added a lot more detail to my post in response to down vote.  Please don't down vote me without leaving a comment of what is expected in this space.

Comment: How to install NecroBrowser? Have you Googled it? You say that you "googled it to death" but the top result is the Github repo for it ...

Comment: There is no "patch" for man-in-the-middle attacks

Comment: The link you share above includes a link (in the same paragraph you quote) to the source article which includes answers to your question.

Comment: This post is lacking some basic research

Comment: Wow four downvotes.  What a tough crowd.  I saw the GitHub where the exploit itself is published, read the FBI warning and that's all I can find.  Defeating MFA by passing already MFA-authenticated cookies seems like an important topic.  I hoped the infosec experts could give me insight, as I'm not one myself.  I'm a good google researcher, just not much to find.  I guess questions in this space must be extremely specific or just don't post it.

Comment: No, one of the canned reasons for downvotes is "does not show any research effort". As I clearly explained, the link you provided answers your questions. You appear to have not read the available material carefully. The result is that your questions are difficult to answer because you have a misunderstanding of the core concepts.

Comment: @pghcpa I'm sorry you got the wrong vibe from the site. It's just a little discouraging for those of us trying to help when the answer is a quick web search of the title (or key words) away, or the answer is clearly stated in a linked article. I also recognize that such things may not be so obvious if you are new to this, but the question does not really show what research was done. Anyway, hope your question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

> a security specialist says it can be defeated with NecroBrowser, which
>   can capture and transmit an already MFA-authenticated cookie.

That's likely not an incorrect statement, but it misses the point. Without a doubt, adding (especially requiring) MFA is a huge improvement to any organization's security posture. Sure, it can be bypassed by an attacker if they can successfully phish a user into logging in through an attacker-controlled proxy, but this is not a fault of the technology itself. If a user is providing sensitive information (login credentials, session information) to an attacker, all bets are off, and any security mechanisms can simply be sidestepped.

> What steps would a user need to take to install NecroBrowser?

I don't think any "user" of yours would be the one installing it, but installation instructions were on Necrobrowser's GitHub page, I believe. It's probably as easy as `docker run muraenateam/necrobrowser`.

> Has this been patched? Any links to the prevention and mitigation
>   details?

What is there to be patched (other than the human brain)? Again, if a user is phished, the blame probably falls on the user or their training. That, or inadequate network security policies that allowed a user to receive an email and click on a strange link to a sketchy domain that was registered only yesterday (for example).

So, the best solution would be to educate users on the dangers and common forms of phishing. Ensure they check the domain name of the current website before entering any credentials. You could probably also supplement user training with some network-based countermeasures to prevent or possibly alert on potential phishing campaigns, but this would likely fall under a separate question.

Comment: Yeah, I've done all that.  It's a group that gets e-mail from all over.  Some of them, even those very educated and intelligent, just don't seem to get the concept of not clicking.  I can put in phishing tests.  The advised next step is to put monitoring software on endpoints and networks to detect any unusual activity.  Otherwise, I've learned, eventually one user in a group is going to compromise their credentials no matter what.  Was hoping maybe for something that stops browsers from passing on authenticated cookies, but guess that doesn't exist.  Thx for thoughtful answer.

Comment: Browsers need to pass on authentication tokens/cookies because that's how authentication works.